# WPF : Combo-box Scrolling by MouseWheel works, but scroll bar clicking does not work

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpf-controls

I am stuck in the strange situation with WPF `Combo-box`, Scrolling by Mouse wheel is perfectly working, But when clicked on mouse down arrow of Scrollbar, Items hide, Same happens when trying to drag the scroll bar.

I am using below `XAML` code

```
<ComboBox  Name="cmbPageNumber" >
     <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
               <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="item_PreviewMouseDown"/>
         </Style>
     </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>    

  void item_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBoxItem cmbitem = sender as ComboBoxItem;
        cmbitem.IsSelected = true;
        string value = cmbitem.Content.ToString();

        OVTreeItem item = CurrentTreeItemForPaging;
        if (item != null && item.PageCounts >= Convert.ToInt32(value))
            item.GotoPage = Convert.ToInt32(value);

        PagingInfo(item);
        EnableDisablePagingButtons();
        this.cmbPageNumber.IsDropDownOpen = false;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

To populate combobox, I am using  below code

```
       for (int i = 1; i <= item.PageCounts; i++)
            {
                cmbPageNumber.Items.Add(i);

            }
```

The interesting thing, When I do right click on `combo-box` and reopen again, then mouse click and scroll by drag working.

Please help me.

Comment: is there any logic written to close or something like that written in PreviewMouseDown event?

Comment: Code updated for event PreviewMouseDown

Comment: More code is needed. How do you populate the combobox? Is there a methods that updates the items in the combobox while you do selects?

Comment: Combo-box population code updated

Comment: Still the code is not sufficient, when do you populate combobox? Do you have any other mouse event handlers?

Comment: That is the only code, I have the populate combo box on timer_Tick, as the value of combox adds time to time.

Comment: Looks fishy to me... You are setting an ItemStyle to the Container. Why dont you use `Combobox.Resources` and put your ItemStyle there?

Comment: if you put these codes in a new project you'll see nothing is wrong with it. so you need to post the relevant code or your bounty will most likely get wasted in a week.

Comment: My `xaml` page is using in WndowsForm application as a Hosted Service. Is this causes an issue?